# how to authenticate to box in my html5 based mobile application

Tags: javascript, box-api, mobile-application

I need to integrate the box access to my html5 based mobile application but not really getting how to get the authorization code ?

- is it possible to use the JavaScript function for redirect_uri ?
- is there anyway I can pass the username and password to login to box ? or it has to go through the box login page only ?
- if it has to go through the box login page only then how I can integrate it in my app ? do I get the complete html page in response which I can show to user in my app ?
- Is there any sample code available ?

your help is very much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Hi I could gigure out the authentication part, basically I got clartity on the redirect_uri, now I have using the custom uri and my application gets launched(reentry) after the authentication and do recieve the code.   I need help on the browser display, currently I am launching the browser using the url 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<my_client_id>  and the browser page for authentication are not the mobile pages and it is very difficult enter the credential, so is there any way I can get the authentication page for mobile display ?

Comment: Hi I could gigure out the authentication part, basically I got clartity on the redirect_uri, now I have using the custom uri and my application gets launched(reentry) after the authentication and do recieve the code. I need help on the browser display, currently I am launching the browser using the url 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<my_client_id> and the browser page for authentication are not the mobile pages and it is very difficult enter the credential, so is there any way I can get the authentication page for mobile display ?